# agregar datos a un registro de una lista de python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

tengo una lista de con los partidos de futbol que se van a disputar los próximos días

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría añadir una columna más con datos estadísticos según la liga a la que pertenece cada partido, pero este dato lo saco de otra web diferente a la que hago el scraping para obtener la lista de partidos y es común para todos los partidos de esa liga, digamos que de esta segunda web sólo obtengo una estadística general de la liga.

Hay alguna forma de agregar este dato a la primera lista?

No se si pudiera poner un condicional
"if 'Liga Profesional Argentina' 'agregar' 90%"
"elif 'Clausura Colombia' 'agregar' 80%"

Estos datos de las ligas los puedo agregar manualmente porque son pocos y no cambian muy a menudo.

Muchas gracias a todos

Incluyo el código completo para que me podáis ayudar y no vayáis a ciegas. Muchas gracias

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

def obtener_stats(func_stats):
    stats_dict = {}
    
    date = func_stats.find('div', attrs={'class':'info match-link'})
    if date:
        stats_dict['date'] = date.get('starttime').replace('T',' ').replace(':00+00:00','')
    else:
        stats_dict['date'] = '-'
 
    draw = func_stats.find('div', attrs={'class':'content-box draw'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'cont'})
    if draw:
        stats_dict['draw'] = draw.get_text('/',strip=True).replace('%','')[4:10]
    else:
        stats_dict['draw'] = '-' 
        
    homeRank = func_stats.find('div', attrs={'class':'position t1'})
    if homeRank:
        stats_dict['homeRank'] = homeRank.get_text()
    else:
        stats_dict['homeRank'] = '-'    
            
    homeTeam = func_stats.find('p', attrs={'itemprop':'homeTeam'})
    if homeTeam:
        stats_dict['homeTeam'] = homeTeam.get_text('/', strip=True)
    else:
        stats_dict['homeTeam'] = '-'

    homeGoals = func_stats.find('div', attrs={'class':'content-box t-1'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'poss-box'})
    if homeGoals:
        stats_dict['homeGoals'] = homeGoals.get_text('/', strip=True).replace('/Probabilidad gana/',' - ').replace('/Goles esperados','')
    else:
        stats_dict['homeGoals'] = '-'     
        
    awayGoals = func_stats.find('div', attrs={'class':'content-box t-2'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'poss-box'})
    if awayGoals:
        stats_dict['awayGoals'] = awayGoals.get_text('/', strip=True).replace('/Probabilidad gana/',' - ').replace('/Goles esperados','')
    else:
        stats_dict['awayGoals'] = '-'     

    awayTeam = func_stats.find('p', attrs={'itemprop':'awayTeam'})
    if awayTeam:
        stats_dict['awayTeam'] = awayTeam.get_text('/', strip=True)
    else:
        stats_dict['awayTeam'] = '-'     
     
    awayRank = func_stats.find('div', attrs={'class':'position t2'})
    if awayRank:
        stats_dict['awayRank'] = awayRank.get_text()
    else:
        stats_dict['awayRank'] = '-' 
        
    competition = func_stats.find('h3', attrs={'class':'competition'})
    if competition:
        stats_dict['competition'] = competition.get_text('/', strip=True)
    else:
        stats_dict['competition'] = '-'
   
    return stats_dict

df = pd.DataFrame()

lista_competiciones = [
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/ligue_1',
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/escocia',
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/portugal',
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/segunda_brasilena',
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/japon',
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/liga_republica_irlanda',
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/premier',
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/segunda',
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/bundesliga_2',
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/j_two_league',
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/brasil',
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/league_one',
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/ligue_2',
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/primera_division_argentina',
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/first_division',
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/vitalis',
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/serie_b',
    'https://es.besoccer.com/competicion/suecia'
]

lista_diaria = []
urlppal = 'https://es.besoccer.com/livescore/2022-09-25'
for i in range(1,6):
    url = urlppal+f'/{i}'
    lista_diaria.append(url)
    
lista_scrapear = lista_diaria + lista_competiciones 

for url in lista_scrapear:
    besoccer = requests.get(url)
    s_besoccer = BeautifulSoup(besoccer.text, 'lxml')
    try:
        matches = s_besoccer.find('div', attrs={'class':'comp-matches'}).find_all('a', attrs={'data-status':'-1'})
    except Exception as e1:
        print(i,'.- La url ',url,' no se pudo scrapear')
        print(i,'.-',e1)
        print(i,'.- Probando otra configuración...')
        try:
            matches = s_besoccer.find('div', attrs={'class':'matches'}).find_all('a', attrs={'data-status':'-1'})
        except Exception as e2:
            print(i,'.- La url ',url,' no se pudo scrapear')
            print(i,'.-',e2)

    links_matches = [match.get('href') for match in matches]
    for i in range(len(links_matches)):
        list_analisis = []
        r_match = requests.get(links_matches[i])
        s_match = BeautifulSoup(r_match.text, 'lxml')
        find_analisis = s_match.find('div', attrs={'class':'menu-scroll'}).select('a[href*="analisis"]')
        try:
            analisis = find_analisis[0]
            link_analisis = analisis.get('href')
            r_link_analisis = requests.get(link_analisis)
            s_link_analisis = BeautifulSoup(r_link_analisis.text, 'lxml')
            df = df.append(obtener_stats(s_link_analisis), ignore_index = True)
            print(i,'.- Scrapeando',url)
            print(i,'.-', link_analisis)
        except Exception as e3:
            print(i,'.- La url ',links_matches[i],' no tiene sección análisis')
            print(i,'.-',e3)

df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})
```

Comment: pensaba que con la foto del ejemplo podíais haceros una idea y de momento sólo decirme si se pueden añadir elementos a una columna nueva según un condicionante

Comment: o sea, según la foto, la última columna que tengo es competición, pues sería agregar una columna nueva (creo que eso sí se puede hacer), pero que el contenido de esa columna sea un condicional según los datos de la columna competition, si la columna competition contiene 'Argentina' agregar el valor 90% por ejemplo

Comment: Seguramente sí se puede.

Comment: eso espero, que sí se pueda, porque me vendría muy bien. Pero tienes alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?? sólo un poco de orientación y yo seguiré investigando, pero ahora mismo estoy en un callejón sin salida.
Muchas gracias

Comment: @CandidMoe perdón, no es una lista, es un DataFrame, no se si es a eso a lo que te refieres con que no se ve ninguna lista

Comment: he puesto todo el código, lo que no aparece aún son los datos que quiero incluir en la nueva columna, pero ya te digo que serían unos porcentajes y los incluiría manualmente, no tengo por qué scrapear otra web (aunque no estaría mal del todo, pero todo a su momento)

Comment: Buen día, no entiendo cual es el error que te impide hacerlo ni lo que has intentado para lograrlo.

Answer (score 0):

pues siguiendo un poco con mi investigación he encontrado la forma de hacerlo con el método .loc() .
Lo que hago es que llamo al DataFrame, busco parte del texto en la columna concreta y le indico el nombre de la nueva columna y el contenido. La verdad es que es realmente fácil pero antes no tenía ni idea de por donde empezar.

Pongo aquí el código por si puedo ayudar a alguien:

```
`df.loc[df.competition.str.contains('Superliga China'), "newcolumn"] = '91%`'
```

Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda